# iDrac 7 serial console commands

Tags: drac

I know how to redirect iDrac 7 to Com2 on a Dell R620, however, despite being able to see post messages and BIOS through putty when connected to the serial port through a DB9 cable, I can't seem to do anything else.
There are a few small shortcuts I'm given before post, but other than that, nothing.

Also, the Dell iDrac manuals or server manuals make no mention of any commands, only how to set things up but nothing else.

I want to know if there is a different command through which I could get into the iDrac recovery console as per this guy who managed to do it on iDrac 5 but his commands don't work for me.

https://www.mcbsys.com/blog/2010/03/fixing-drac-5-error-remote-access-controller-initialization-failure/

Any thoughts?

The keyboard shortcuts I'm being shown before post are about doing ctrl-alt-del and such, but, nothing about getting into the recovery console...

I need this because iDrac and the lifecycle controller are both bricked, I have literally tried everything else so please skip any suggestions about that as I literally have exhausted everything, even talking to Dell Support though it's out of warranty or support...